# Zohar about the 18-19th century

Tags: history, mysticism-kabbalah, zohar

I saw a quote one time--I believe it was in an Artscroll sefer--from the Zohar about how there would be tremendous spiritual and cultural revelations that would occur around the 18th-19th centuries. (I believe that was when it was.) Does anyone know where that quote is, or what it actually says? (Forgive the ambiguity, I don't have much more to go on here.)

Comment: Yehuda, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks for bringing your question here! I hope you get helpful answers, and that you'll look around and find other information of interest, perhaps among our other [tag:zohar] or [tag:history] questions. See you around!

Comment: @robev More like that question itself has a possible answer to the question here.

Comment: I think it is wrong to mark this question as a duplicate of the other. The source quoted in that question answers the question here - not the answers there. I say that the better approach would be to have the relevant passages quoted in an answer here, and a link to that question provided as a source, if needed\desired.